# Allow user to install from unknown sources on Android 5.0

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have Nexus 10 and have 2 users on it.
On Android 4.4 both Users could install application from unknown sources.

After upgrade to Android 5.0 admin user has *Security-Unknown Sources*  flag is "on" but secondary User has this flag greyed and disabled.

How can I switch it on?

Comment: You can't turn it off but you can bypass it using abp. Related issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79728

Comment: Almost close: [How to install apk in 2nd user of android 5.0 without playstore](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/119312)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be possible to do it with a rooted device, but on Android 5.0 only the primary user can install apps from Unknown Sources.

Comment: It's very bad news. Looking forward for any workaround.

Comment: @algot I'm hoping this is a workaround: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96026/if-the-owner-installs-an-app-can-a-secondary-profile-use-it

Comment: @algot and another one :) https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/96027/can-i-switch-owner-and-secondary-status-for-two-profiles