# If the owner installs an app can a secondary profile use it?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, profiles, side-loading, unknown-sources

It appears that in Lollipop [secondary user profiles can no longer install APKs from unknown sources](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88077).

So, if I install an APK from the owner profile, can I give a secondary profile access to that app?

*Suggested tag: secondary-profile*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the user is a Restricted User.  When you first create the user, you must choose "Restricted User".  Then you can choose what apps the user can access (4.2 style).

Comment: Additional note: On Lollipop, the feature seems only available on Android tablet, [not phone](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/92186/creating-restricted-accounts-on-mobile-lollipop)