# Can I switch owner and secondary status for two profiles?

Tags: profiles

I have a tablet with an owner and secondary profile. Can I switch them so that the owner becomes a secondary, and the secondary becomes the owner?

*Suggested tag: secondary-profile*

Answer (score 2):

From my (cursory) checking right now - I would say **no**.

From the Owner Profile, the only options present for Secondary Profiles are to `Remove the Profile` and set whether they can `Make Phone Calls/Send SMS`.

From within the Secondary User Profile there is only the option to rename the profile.