# How to install apk in 2nd user of android 5.0 without playstore

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, apk, side-loading, unknown-sources

So, android 5.0.2 doesn't allow side loading of apks for 2nd user (irrespective of whether it is guest or standard user). "Unknown Sources" is disabled and is uncheckable. And I use a pure Cyanogen Mod 12 (android 5.0.2) without any Google apps. So, there is no Play Store app.

But I have root access.

As shown in the pics, Unknown Sources is Uncheckable and installation is blocked.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: install-blocked]
[image: IMG: unknown sources uncheckable]

With this situation, how can i install apks on to the 2nd user account??

**EDIT:**

It seems Google intentionally (in the name of security) blocked sideloading apks for 2nd user in android 5.0.2. There is a bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79728). And sideloading was reenabled in android 5.1.

I will post how to sideload apks on lolipop 2nd user using adb. If this can be done without adb please post.

Comment: enable sideloading

Comment: How? Unknown sources is untickable in 2nd user in lolipop 5.0.2 .

Comment: amd first user? I think it's untickable because the main user has disabled it. so any other user can't active it

Comment: Main user has it enabled. 2nd user has only option to install apps from play store. Device without gapps are affected...

Comment: it's working on cm 12.1. I tried it right now.

Comment: @Schwertspize CM12.1 runs Android 5.1.x while OP noted Android 5.0.2 (CM12). I got confused first too but later amended my answer. :)

Comment: @Firelord I know that cm 12.1 is based on android 5.1. I just tried it and wanted to share that it's cm 12 only.

Answer (score 6):

Using the command,

```
adb install -r whatever.apk
```

will install the application in 2nd user of android 5.0.2 .

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79728#c72)

Comment: what if the 2nd user can't enable developer options and so can't enable usb debugging ?

Comment: 2nd user cannot enable developer options and usb debugging. When 1st user enables usb debugging and installs this way, the application will appear to 2nd user. If 1st user willingly disables usb debugging, then there is nothing much 2nd user can do in this regard..

Comment: If settings.apk is recompiled with this (https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Settings/commit/338ab4561d7e06619b43f3634be7414afe5389d1) commit or this (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/ceceb2a) included, then it will be fixed.

Comment: Is there a way without need to use `ADB`? Any method that might require root or custom recovery maybe?